# How to show a semi transparent overlay with button (!) on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

i am using ASP.Net to edit an image. I would like to have onMouseOver an semi transparent overlay on my image which show me some button. One important thing is, that some of these buttons are role-based so that i must be able from code behind to set those button visible/innvisible. How could i do this?

[image: Wanted result]

Comment: Not really a javascript question

Comment: @Lou Why not? Is it possible with pure css and asp.net without javascript?

Comment: There is the css rule selector:hover

Comment: Almost forgot, there is also animation in css.

Comment: @nocturns2 I think i have a way to do that. I googled around and found this for example: http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/overlay.html. I have seen that the overlay is simply another div. I would put my controls inside this overlay div and could view it on mouse over. I will it try tomorrow and post the result.

Comment: It sounds like that should do the trick! Happy New Years!!